# What does this function syntax do in php?

Tags: php, function, syntax

I'm just looking through a php vendor class and I've seen this. 
The reason is I'm getting a syntax error on this function running PHP 7.0.29.

```
public function funcName(): ?string
{
    // do something
}
```

Thank you

Comment: That is [PHP 7.1 syntax for nullable type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php). The function may return a string or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a new feature in php7.1.x.

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark.

php manual [php7.1.x New features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)